# How to loop tr, td of a table based on letter instead of number

Tags: php, html

Currently I have a table and is currently coded as:

```
$min_hor = $min_ver = 1;
$max_hor = $max_ver = 3;


?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    .table{
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="text-center">
    <table class="table" style="width:70%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <?php for($j=$min_hor; $j<=$max_hor; $j++){ ?>
                <th><?php echo str_pad($j, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></th>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php for($i=$min_ver;$i<=$max_ver;$i++){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $i; ?></th>
                    <?php for($j=$min_hor; $j<=$max_hor; $j++){ ?>
                        <td><?php echo $i.'-'.str_pad($j, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This display table as shown in attached screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

Now, I have one additional array as `$letter_array = array('A','B');` This array is could be bigger than this one and could be upto `D,E,F,...`

Now, I need to include this `A,B` into the table header something like as shown in screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of table2]

This is where I became helpless. I couldn't find how could I loop this. Although, to make things easier, I have included codepen link of html code.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/prying/pen/KKPoQaw)

Comment: Check `chr()` and `ord()` functions, they convert numbers to the corresponding ASCII character and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

How about we keep headers in 2 different Arrays and then perform a loop.following is the pseudocode which i think will work.

```
string a[16]={'01','02','03',......,'B'};
string b[17]={'1','2','3',....,'B'};

 <table class="table" style="width:70%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            foreach(var item in a)
            {
               <th>{{item}}</th>
            }
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        foreach(var item2 in b)
        { 
         <tr>
           <td>{{item2}}</td>
           foreach(var item in a)
           {
              <td>{{item2}}_{{item}}</td>
           }
         </tr>
         } 
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Now, before generating table we need elements at array A and B. to generate the array i.e a and b we can do following :

```
int min_hor=1;
int max_hor=3;
var a_output=[];
var a_inputLetter=['A','B'];

   //first for number only.here let us create a string and push to a_output.
   for(int i=min_hor,i<=max_hor;i++)
   {
      a_output.Add('0'+i); 
   }

   //second let us use Number Letter Combination
   foreach(var item in a_inputLetter)
   {
      for(int i=min_hor;i<=max_hor;i++)
      {
         a_output.Add('0'+{{i}}_{{item}});
      }
   }
   //third for letter number combination
   foreach(var item in a_inputLetter)
   {
      for(int i=min_hor;i<=max_hor;i++)
      {
         a_output.Add({{item}}_{{i}});
      }
   }
   //and finally for letter_only
   foreach(var item in a_inputLetter)
   { 
      a_output.Add({{item}});
   }

//similarly do for Array B as well to generate the second array.
```

Comment: I didn't understand your code, however, I got an idea of storing these values in two different array and loop them in foreach instead of for loop